# why do I get wierd output instead of image

Tags: c, image

> when reading the file data into file_buff and then using send() to send the data out to the browser I get weird data like this->(ÿØÿà�JFIF�) instead of the image that is supposed to show up. I can send data like text out to the browser but can't seem to send the image data out.

```
void *connectionThread(void *socket_desc){

    char buffer[100000];
    int newsockfd = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int n;
    magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_ERROR|MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    magic_load(myt,NULL);
    char file_buff [800000];
    struct stat filestat;
    bzero(buffer,256);
    FILE * fp;

 while (1)
     {memset(buffer, 0, 100000);n = read(newsockfd,buffer,100000);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("it is something here: %s",buffer);

    char *token = strtok(buffer," ");
    if(token !=NULL)
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    token = strtok(token,"\n");
    token = strtok(token,"/");

    fp = fopen ("Koala.jpg", "rb");

    write(newsockfd,"Content-Length: 780831\r\n",strlen("Content-Length: 780831\n"));

    write(newsockfd,"Content-Type: ",strlen("Content-type: "));
    write(newsockfd,magic_file(myt,token),strlen(magic_file(myt,token))); //get Content-type
    write(newsockfd,"\n\n",strlen("\n\n"));
            //knowing the size of image is 780831
    fread(file_buff, sizeof(char), 780831 + 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        send(newsockfd, file_buff, 780831,0);



    if ((strncmp(buffer,"quit",4) == 0)) //quit
    break;
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message\n May I have another\n",40);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

        write(newsockfd,"Ok, I am quitting\n",18);
     }  

    close(newsockfd);
    magic_close(myt);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems as if the browser does not interpret the data as an image; are you sure about the content type you submit?

Comment: yea I know the image is a .jpg and that the method magic_file() ouputs jpeg for the content type.

Comment: check the line endings -- in `write(newsockfd,"Content-Length: 780831\r\n",strlen("Content-Length: 780831\n"));` you're not writing the newline (the string in the `strlen()` doesn't match the other one).

Comment: oh thank you didn't see that, but it also didn't help with the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to changes the header that you are sending. Set you content-type as Multi-part data.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\ncontent-type: multipart\r\ncontent-length:%ld\r\nConnnection: Close; 
I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes ha just figured out that I didn't have HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n in the header it works now thank you.